# Collections in Hibernate as final with CascadeType.ALL and clear() in setter()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have following Hibernate entity

```
<!-- language: java -->
@Entity(name = "Someentity")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class SomeEntity extends SPCEntity{

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bom", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private final Set<Note> notes = new HashSet<>();

public void setNotes(final Set<Note> notes) {
    this.notes.clear();
    this.notes.addAll(notes);
}
}
```

The according note class

```
@Entity(name = "NOTE")
    public class BomNote extends Note {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
@JoinColumn(name = "bom_id")
private SomeEntity bom; 

    ... getters and setters...
}
```

Is it risky to use final for the notes Collection and is it risky to clear the notes set before adding all recived notes.

As far as i know it - is not to modify the persistent collections which hibernate provides. with this solution the hiberate list is never set in the object, but it is always using the inital list object.

This may lead to confusing side effects with hibernate, especially with cascade type ALL?

Appretiate any help and suggestions.

Comment: What happens whe you try it? How could Hibernate implement its lazy loading if it can't replace your set with its own lazy set?

Comment: Currently it works and nothing unexpected happens, so far. As far as I know Hibernate is using reflaction to set it.

Comment: I thought Hibernate disallowed this. But anyway, if it assigns a new value to the final field, it's not really final anymore. So make sure your code treats the final field as a non final one.